# Betting Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, formula

I am creating a program that is supposed to calculate and log betting data for a competition.  I have come up with a rudimentary calculation that I believe works for the time being but I want it to be more efficient.

The variables I am currently using include:

- Win/Lose Ratio
- Average Match time (in seconds)
- The total amount that everyone has bet on this person

There are two competitors during each match and their historical data is pulled out of my database.

Given the above variables, I need someone to give me some guidance as to a good algorithm, formula, or established method that is used to calculate the lump sum of money I should risk on each fight.

Comment: Please show us the code you already have, and tell us what question you have about it.

Comment: The code is very long and I am halfway embarrassed about it.  But pretty much I created the highest possible score between the two and then compared them to that score.  Very much the same way school grades are calculated. This is why I wanted to streamline it.

Comment: I saw that my question wasn't the clearest, so for future readers I have rephrased the question to directly ask for what is wanted.

Comment: I reworded it again.  I believe it states exactly what is needed along with any information that I have to put into the formula. Other than that, I am not sure how to get this out of "on hold" status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any head-to-head system should probably use the [Elo Rating System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system). It provides a way of assessing a competitors skill as compared to the other competitors they've played and their results.

Difference in Elo rating can easily give you good odds. For example a 200 point difference in rating points translates to roughly 1 to 3 odds. A 400 point difference roughly to 1 to 15 odds.

I would use your historical data to generate an Elo rating for each participant and then base your calculations on those odds.

Other useful links:

- http://homepage.math.uiowa.edu/~idarcy/COURSES/151/SPRING09/JMadisonPPTRatingSystems.pdf
- http://www.chess-iecc.com/ratings/algor.html

Comment: Per this solution, below is are the sites I am using for my examples if anyone is interested:

http://homepage.math.uiowa.edu/~idarcy/COURSES/151/SPRING09/JMadisonPPTRatingSystems.pdf

http://www.chess-iecc.com/ratings/algor.html

Comment: Those are good links, I'll include them